# get text in td's in a table with specific id and tr with specific attribute

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Given an html like this:

```
    page_html = '''
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div1">
            <h1>h1 text</h1>
            <div id="div div1">text div div1
            </div>
            <p>text in p</p>
            <table id="tab1" border="1">
                <tr id="tab1 tr1" class="class1">
                    <td><a href="/info/tab1/tr1/td1">tab1 tr1 td 1</a></td>
                    <td><a href="/info/tab1/tr1/td2">tab1 tr1 td 2</a></td>
                    <td><a href="/info/tab1/tr1/td3">tab1 tr1 td 3</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="tab1 tr2" class="class1">
                    <td><a href="/info/tab1/tr2/td1">tab1 tr2 td 1</a></td>
                    <td><a href="/info/tab1/tr2/td2">tab1 tr2 td 2</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="tab1 tr3" class="class2">
                    <td><a href="/info/tab1/tr3/td1">tab1 tr3 td 1</a></td>
                    <td><a href="/info/tab1/tr3/td2">tab1 tr3 td 2</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table id="tab2" border="1">
                <tr id="tab2 tr1" class="class2">
                    <td><a href="/info/tab2/tr1/td1">tab2 tr1 td 1</a></td>
                    <td><a href="/info/tab2/tr1/td2">tab2 tr1 td 2</a></td>
                    <td><a href="/info/tab2/tr1/td3">tab2 tr1 td 3</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="tab2 tr2" class="class2">
                    <td><a href="/info/tab2/tr2/td1">tab2 tr2 td 1</a></td>
                    <td><a href="/info/tab2/tr2/td2">tab2 tr2 td 2</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="tab2 tr3" class="class3">
                    <td><a href="/info/tab2/tr3/td1">tab2 tr3 td 1</a></td>
                    <td><a href="/info/tab2/tr3/td2">tab2 tr3 td 2</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
</body>
</html>   
'''
```

I would like to get the text from td's in table with `id=tab2` where tr's have attribute `class=class2`, corresponding to:

```
            <tr id="tab2 tr1" class="class2">
                <td><a href="/info/tab2/tr1/td1">tab2 tr1 td 1</a></td>
                <td><a href="/info/tab2/tr1/td2">tab2 tr1 td 2</a></td>
                <td><a href="/info/tab2/tr1/td3">tab2 tr1 td 3</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="tab2 tr2" class="class2">
                <td><a href="/info/tab2/tr2/td1">tab2 tr2 td 1</a></td>
                <td><a href="/info/tab2/tr2/td2">tab2 tr2 td 2</a></td>
            </tr>
```

My partial solution is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

bsobj = BeautifulSoup(page_html)
res = bsobj.find('table', id='tab2').findAll('tr', {'class':'class2'})
```

but I am not able to extract the text.

Trying with list comprehension:

```
[td.text for td in res]
```

gets the general (right) result but as a list of the two tr's and with anomalous `\n`, that is:

> ['\ntab2 tr1 td 1\ntab2 tr1 td 2\ntab2 tr1 td 3\n',  '\ntab2 tr2 td
>   1\ntab2 tr2 td 2\n']

Is there a cleaner way to get the text for each td satisfying my conditions on table and tr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ResultSet objects can be treated like a list and used in a list comprehension directly. You can use a nested list comprehension to first get the  all the `tr` and then all the `td` from each of the `tr` without storing  intermediate results.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
bsobj = BeautifulSoup(page_html,'html.parser')
res = [td.text for tr in bsobj.find('table', id='tab2').findAll('tr', {'class':'class2'}) for td in tr.findAll('td')]
print(res)
```

Output

```
['tab2 tr1 td 1', 'tab2 tr1 td 2', 'tab2 tr1 td 3', 'tab2 tr2 td 1', 'tab2 tr2 td 2']
```

Answer (score 0):

A better and cleaner way to access table is using Vanilla JavaScript.

First of all you should better add an `id` to your `<table id="myTable">` element to avoid conflicts.

Here is the way to read all `<td>` from table element by `<tr>` -

```
let table = document.getElementById('myTable');
let trs = Array.from(table.getElementsByTagName('tr'));

trs.forEach(tr => {
  let tds = Array.from(table.getElementsByTagName('td'));

  tds.forEach(td => {
    console.log(td.innerHTML);
  })
})
```

Live in action - https://jsitor.com/A3cx88q5h

Comment: Probably I was not clear about the language. I am interesting in python 3 solutions. Thank you, anyway.